# Python: partial that takes three arguments

Tags: python, syntax, partial

I'm trying to learn Python by reading the book [Data Science from Scratch by Joel Grus](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Data-Science-Scratch-Principles-Python/dp/149190142X), and on page 94 they describe how to approximate a derivative of f = x^2 using the following code

```
def difference_quotient(f, x, h):
    return (f(x + h) - f(x)) / h

def square(x):
    return x * x

def derivative(x):
    return 2 * x

derivative_estimate = partial(difference_quotient, square, h=0.00001)

# plot to show they're basically the same
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = range(-10,10)
plt.title("Actual Derivatives vs. Estimates")
plt.plot(x, map(derivative, x), 'rx', label='Actual')
plt.plot(x, map(derivative_estimate, x), 'b+', label='Estimate')
plt.legend(loc=9)
plt.show()
```

Everything works fine, but when I change the line `derivative_estimate = partial(difference_quotient, square, h=0.00001)` to `derivative_estimate = partial(difference_quotient, f=square, h=0.00001)` (because I think that is clearer to read), then I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "page_93.py", line 37, in <module>
    plt.plot(x, map(derivative_estimate, x), 'b+', label='Estimate')
TypeError: difference_quotient() got multiple values for keyword argument 'f'
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Where the function `partial` comes from? Some library? I believe it is not built in.

Comment: @quapka [coming from `functools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Comment: If you're lucky, [Joel himself](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1076346/joel) may answer your question. :)

Comment: `derivative_estimate = partial(f=difference_quotient, x =square ,  h=0.00001)` is the right way to do it. If the first argument is passed as a keyword argument then the rest of your arguments must  be passed as  keyword only arguments, otherwise you'll get `SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg` if you run Python 3.X

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was answered and perfectly explained in this topic:

- [functools.partial wants to use a positional argument as a keyword argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755463/functools-partial-wants-to-use-a-positional-argument-as-a-keyword-argument)

Which in your case implies that you should pass `x` as a *keyword argument*:

```
plt.plot(x, [derivative_estimate(x=item) for item in x], 'b+', label='Estimate')
```

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion works and I understand it, so I have accepted your answer. But I still don't really see why the code that I suggested failed. I have read the link you provided and understand it in that example, but I don't see at what point I use the same argument twice.

Comment: @Hunter sure, when you call `map(derivative_estimate, x)` - python would actually call `derivative_estimate(x[0])`, then `derivative_estimate(x[1])` etc. `x[0]`, `x[1]` would be passed as the first positional argument to `difference_quotient` which is `f`. And, since you specify `f` keyword argument, Python complains that `f` was specified multiple times.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Ahhh I see, great. Thank you!!