# Pass a variable number of arguments to the map function

Tags: python

Suppose I have a function whose the prototype is:

```
def my_func(fixed_param, *args)
```

I would like to run this function with multiple arguments (not necessary the same number of arguments for each run) such as:

```
res = map(partial(my_func, fixed_param=3), [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

where [1, 2, 3] and [1, 2, 3, 4] respectively correspond to the first and second set of parameters for args.

But this line of code fails with the following error:

```
TypeError: my_func() got multiple values for keyword argument 'fixed_param'
```

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24755463/5018771) help you ?

Answer (score 6):

I would not be so sure about `map` vs list comprehension performance, as oftentimes it's a question of the function you use. Anyway, your options are:

```
map(lambda x: my_func(3, *x), ...)
```

Or

```
from itertools import starmap

starmap(partial(my_func, 3), ...)
```

Like all function in `itertools`, `starmap` returns an iterator, hence you must pass it to the `list` constructor, if you want a list. That will be slower than a listcomp for sure.

**EDIT** Benchmarks:

```
In [1]: def my_func(x, *args):
   ...:     return (x, ) + args
   ...: 

In [2]: from functools import partial

In [3]: from itertools import starmap

In [4]: import random

In [5]: samples = [range(random.choice(range(10))) for _ in range(100)]

In [6]: %timeit map(lambda x: my_func(3, *x), samples)
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.2 µs per loop

In [7]: %timeit list(starmap(partial(my_func, 3), samples))
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.2 µs per loop

In [8]: %timeit [my_func(3, *s) for s in samples]
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.8 µs per loop
```

For the sake of comparison, lets change the function a bit

```
In [9]: def my_func(x, args):
       ...:     return (x, )  + tuple(args)
       ...: 

In [10]: %timeit [my_func(3, s) for s in samples]
10000 loops, best of 3: 37.6 µs per loop

In [11]: %timeit map(partial(my_func, 3), samples)
10000 loops, best of 3: 42.1 µs per loop
```

Once again, list comprehension is faster.

Answer (score 4):

You can unpack the argument list if you use a list comprehension:

```
res= [my_func(3, *args) for args in [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]]
```

But you can't do this with `map`. If you insist on using `map`, you'll need a helper function:

```
def unpack(args):
    return my_func(3, *args)
res= map(unpack, [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your code will work with a few small changes:

```
def f(l, all_args):
    print "Variable", all_args
    print "Fixed", l

map(partial(f, 1), [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]])

>>> Variable [1, 2, 3]
>>> Fixed 1
>>> Variable [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> Fixed 1
```

Comment: Why does the fact to pass '1' instead of 'l=1' in the partial function work?

Comment: @floflo29 because `partial` matches position arguments, you should only pass keyword arguments if you want to override this behaviour.

Comment: @EliKorvigo ok but writing 'l=1' does not thus override it?

Comment: @floflo29 in this case it makes no difference, because `l` is the first argument.